# Adding strings at certain places in a text file

Tags: batch-file, text, edit

I have a text file with the following contents:

> -849.4471 1272.173 22.8698 0 0 -1 7.54979E-008 Fire_Esc_6 385 792 24 -1
>   -837.0507 1270.862 28.1249 0 0 -1 7.54979E-008 Fire_Esc_6b 385 792 24 -1
>   -837.0654 1270.879 24.09248 0 0 -1 7.54979E-008 Fire_Esc_6 385 792 24 -1

For each of the lines, I need to

- add `setAttr "sth";` to the beginning of the line
- add `sth` between the first and second numbers
- delete everything on the line from `385` through the end of the line

I'm a total beginner in batch and have no idea where to start. Any help you can give you be greatly appreciated.

I've done until here by somethingDark's help :0

```
FOR /F "tokens=8* delims= " %%G IN (C:\Users\Sherlock\Documents\3DReaperDX\Frames\1.txt) DO ECHO set %%G >12.txt
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far?  I don't see any code.  Have you looked into text search and substitution in batch variables, or parsing fields with `for /f`?

Comment: You are *far* more likely to get an answer, if you write a bit better English... Also, showing desired output formatted the same way as your input would help. And finally, do you really have to use BAT file, and why? Powershell would be much nicer, for example, if you can't install Python or something.

Comment: @hyde - batch is a perfectly acceptable language for this question, especially if the data is consistently formatted like that. A `for /f` loop with the `"tokens=1-12"` option would make short work of that. That said, I'm not going to answer this because "write my code for me" questions are off topic.

Comment: Tnx for your answer but I rather to use bath files,I don't want U to write this batch file for me just explain me how to do that?just explain me how to add something between the first and second numbers plz.

Comment: I can definitely point you in the right direction. You're going to want to use a [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) loop and put the filename inside of the parentheses with no quotes (unless there are spaces in the file name). Where it says options, you want to say "tokens=1-12" since you have 12 space-delimited strings. From there, you can use the loop parameters to construct the string that you want (check out the example at the bottom for an explanation of explicit vs implicit declaration, as it will be crucial to your solution).

Comment: Thank U so much as I said I'm beginner if you show me as a example it's so better cause i didn't understand anything .
You said check out the example at the bottom where?You didn't put any example.

Comment: The example at the bottom of the page I linked. http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html in case you missed it the first time.

Comment: @kmthrongkmthrongi Btw, if you solve this, especially after following hints in comments, and nobody else has written a good answer, then it's always good to write an answer to your own question, with the solution you used.

Comment: Okay I got it a bit.

pause
FOR /F "tokens=1-12* delims=," %%G IN (C:\Users\Sherlock\Documents\3DReaperDX\Frames\1.txt) DO ECHO %%G set >12.txt

FOR /F "usebackq "tokens=1-12* delims=," %%G IN ("C:\Users\Sherlock\Documents\3DReaperDX\Frames\1.txt") DO ECHO %%G

pause
pause

it adds set at the end of the first line can you help me a bit more?

Comment: I'm having trouble telling where one command stops and the next one starts in your comment. Can you please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32323992/edit) to include the code you've used?

Comment: Of course and tnx for your help I edited the question and now code is there look at the up of the page.By this code it gets the Fire_Esc_6 from the third line how can tell it to do it for which line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've made an attempt to solve this yourself, I feel better about showing you what I was imagining for your script.

```
@echo off

:: If 12.txt exists, delete it. This way, the entire file will be recreated when the script is re-run.
:: (If you don't want this to happen and you just want new data added to the end of the file every
::  time the script is run, just delete this part.)
if exist 12.txt del 12.txt


:: An example line looks like this:
:: -849.4471 1272.173 22.8698 0 0 -1 7.54979E-008 Fire_Esc_6 385 792 24 -1

:: Iterate through each line in 1.txt, storing each space-delimited string in a unique variable
:: %%A: -849.4471
:: %%B: 1272.173
:: %%C: 22.8698
:: %%D: 0
:: %%E: 0
:: %%F: -1
:: %%G: 7.54979E-008
:: %%H: Fire_Esc_6
:: Since we don't care about anything after the eighth token, we can just ignore it
:: The redirection command is at the start of the line to avoid an extra space at the end of the line
for /f "tokens=1-8" %%A in (C:\Users\Sherlock\Documents\3DReaperDX\Frames\1.txt) do >>12.txt echo setAttr "sth"; %%A sth %%B %%C %%D %%E %%F %%G %%H
```

Since this script is so short (it's really just three lines with a whole bunch of comments), you could even run this one-liner from the command line:

```
for /f "tokens=1-8" %A in (C:\Users\Sherlock\Documents\3DReaperDX\Frames\1.txt) do >>12.txt echo setAttr "sth"; %A sth %B %C %D %E %F %G %H
```

This will create the file 12.txt with the contents

> setAttr "sth"; -849.4471 sth 1272.173 22.8698 0 0 -1 7.54979E-008 Fire_Esc_6
>   setAttr "sth"; -837.0507 sth 1270.862 28.1249 0 0 -1 7.54979E-008 Fire_Esc_6b
>   setAttr "sth"; -837.0654 sth 1270.879 24.09248 0 0 -1 7.54979E-008 Fire_Esc_6

Comment: Tnx for your help dude but i still have some problems with that look at Second part of my question: on the top of the page I've already uploaded it because I couldn't add codes here.

Comment: @kmthrongkmthrongi - That is a completely different question. You should mark this one as accepted and then ask a second question.

Comment: OK so I maid https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32367624/ignore-some-lines-using-for-f-command

but how can I mark this one as accepted?

Comment: Ok tnx it's done plz help me in new topic linked to this topic right right of the page.